# My React Google Cloud Run app requests to Google API Gateway are blocked by CORS policy. What am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, cors, google-api-gateway

I have a React create-app App running on Google Cloud Run.
On the backend, I've created a Google Cloud Run Django app, and served its API via API Gateway.
I'm using Auth0 to authenticate requests.

On the react side, I've set my proxy in `package.json` as:

```
"proxy": "http://{api gateway url}",
```

While trying locally, whenever the app runs an axios request, I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://{api gateway url}/api/users/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/users/') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In production though, my axios requests aren't re-directed to the proxy and for now all I'm getting are 405 errors.

I've checked that the url is correct and my axios requests has the following headers:

```
headers: AxiosHeaders
  Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT"
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  Authorization: "Bearer {token}"
  Content-Type: "application/json"
```

and in production I've added proxy to my axios requests but this doesn't seem to work.

I've tried enabling CORS both in API gateway config:

```
host: "{api gateway url}"
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "{api gateway url}"
  allowCors: True
```

and in my Django settings.py as well:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

What am I missing? And how can I make sure my requests in prod are being routed correctly?
Would appreciate any lead on this  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [google groups](https://groups.google.com/g/api-gateway-users/c/9CwyQr1c420) discussion, Seems currently `CORS` configuration for `API Gateway` is not supported. As a workaround you can try using [ESPv2 running on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-esp-v2-startup-options#cors).

You can  also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65738206/18265570) by @Cloudkollektiv. And there exists a feature request for the same in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/181537068), you can either add your concern there or create a new issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I set up ESPv2 and now everything works!